# hover change to on mousenter breaks logic

Tags: jquery

```
$('.masterTooltip').hover(function() {
    // hover over code.
    var title = $(this).attr('data-submenu');

    $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
    $('<p class="tooltip"></p>').text(title).appendTo('body');

    var x = $(this).offset();
    var w = $('#collapsed-menu').width();
    $('.tooltip').css({ top: x.top + 'px', left: w + 'px' }).show();
}, function() {
    // Hover out code
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
    $('.tooltip').remove();
});
```

My intention is to make a tooltip which shows a popup box when you hover over the `<a>`. This code works just fine, but because my HTML for this is dynamically loaded it wont work using hover.

```
$('#menuMain-ul').on('mouseenter', '.masterTooltip', function() {

});
```

This was the code only work on my dynamic HTML, but when I combine the two codes together it doesn't work. Can anyone help me use `mouseenter` to make it work?

[Normal Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/whbm0skL/2/) try hover over the text

[COMBINE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/p1114sqL/) noting show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is close. The issue is that when using a delegated event handler you can only assign one event handler at a time, so you need to call `on()` again for the `mouseleave` event. Try this:

```
$('#menuMain-ul').on('mouseenter', '.masterTooltip', function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var title = $el.data('submenu');
    $el.data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
    $('<p class="tooltip"></p>').text(title).appendTo('body').css({
        top: $el.offset().top,
        left: $('#collapsed-menu').width()
    }).show();
}).on('mouseleave', '.masterTooltip', function() {
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
    $('.tooltip').remove();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/p1114sqL/5/)

Also note that I amended the logic slightly to follow best practices.

Comment: Thank you Rory , appreciate.